# Contraction [SUBJECT] + is with proper noun ending in s?

Tags: grammar, contractions

The possessive form (the car of Jesus) would be Jesus' car.

If we say Jesus is 11.  Would it also be Jesus' 11?   Jesus's 11?

Comment: Since the contraction of _is_ has the exact same sound as the noun plural, noun possessive, and 3SgPres verb inflection (/-əz/ after sibilants, /-s/ after voiceless consonants, /-z/ elsewhere), it's hard to tell the difference. If _Jesus_ is pronounced as in English /'dʒizəz/, it wouldn't be contracted with _is_. If it's pronounced as in Spanish /he'sus/, as a normal name, it would get a normal /-əz/ suffix. That's the only way I could make sense out of the sentence _Jesus is 11_.

Comment: Your possessive is incorrect, although a common error. We only omit the `s` if the word ends in `s` because it's a plural.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no similar rule about contractions for words ending in `s`.

Comment: @Barmar Not so. There are plenty of writers (and style guides) who use only an apostrophe to indicate possessives of proper nouns ending in _s_.

Comment: I guess it's changed since I learned the rule when I was growing up.

Comment: "Exceptions are the possessives of ancient proper names in -es and -is, the possessive Jesus', and such forms as for conscience' sake, for righteousness' sake." — [*Elements of Style*](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk.html)

Comment: @Malvolio Those aren’t exceptions, as I have explained a million times before. But people don’t listen. They are exactly and completely predictable. They are not exceptions, for the law has none.

Comment: Can you cite that explanation?

Answer (score 3):

In general. people *avoid* forming a contraction with a word ending in S and the verb "is".

*Of all the diet and fitness "experts", Richard Simmmons's probably the one I like least.* It's not only strange-looking, it's a whole mouthful of mumbles when one tries to say it aloud.

It falls into the same category as contracting "am not" as "ain't". It isn't advisable.

Comment: +2 for 'a whole mouthful of mumbles' which I'd perversely and satirically rephrase as 'mumbles's a mouthful' ;-P

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is using proper names in a contraction---what is the rule? 
For instance, "America's got Talent" is ok, because the apostrophe subs for the letters "ha" in has got Talent. But what about "Travis' got Talent?" That should be wrong because the apostrophe would be substituting for the entire word, "has". So it should be 
Travis's Got Talent, the apostrophe therefore subbing for "ha" like in America's GOt Talent.  Unless they are both wrong....